# How to find the max values from similar groups in an object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have an object like this

```
obj = {
 'ab-adf': 2,
 'ab-d': 3,  
 'cd-23': 1,
 'cd-df': 5,
 'ef-a': 3,
 'ef-nb': 4
};
```

Expected output number or strings: 3, 5, 4   from each ab, cd and ef group.

I am also looking for solution to print it out like this ab-asdf=8, cd-ed=6 etc it should keep the original name with a '=' sign after it.

I know the most traditional way is to use loop and return max value.

```
var max = -Infinity, x;
for( x in obj) {
    if( x.slice(0,2)==='ab' && obj[x] > max) max = obj[x];
    if( x.slice(0,2)==='cd' && obj[x] > max) max = obj[x];
    if( x.slice(0,2)==='ef' && obj[x] > max) max = obj[x];
 //how to return max value from each group ?
}
```

Comment: Would you like to return an array of max values?

Comment: prefer number or strings

Comment: You cannot have two keys of the same name within the same object, and you cannot have a minus sign in an object's key unless the key is in quotes.  I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: xxx = different values. so different keys. yes they are meant to be quotes, obviously..

Comment: That's not a problem, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, JavaScript won't be able to interpret your object because there are special characters in the keys. You'll need to wrap the keys in quotations like this:

```
obj = {
 'ab-xxx': 2,
 'ab-yyy': 3,  
 'cd-xxx': 1,
 'cd-yyy': 6,
 'cd-zzz': 5,
 'ef-xxx': 3,
 'ef-yyy': 4,
};
```

Next, you'll want to store the max values for each group, then join the max values to get the string you were looking for as output.

```
// Get the max values for each prefix
var max = {};
for(var key in obj) {
  var prefix = key.slice(0,2);
  if (max[prefix] === undefined || max[prefix] < obj[key]){
    max[prefix] = obj[key];
  }
}

// Concatenate the max values into a string
var maxString = '';
for(key in max){
  maxString += max[key] + ' ';
}
maxString = maxString.trim();
```

EDIT:

> yes, basically I am also looking for solution to print it out like
>   this ab-asdf=8, cd-ed=6 etc it should keep the original name with a
>   '=' sign after it.

To achieve this output, you can do it this way:

```
// Get the max values for each prefix, and store the max as a string
var max = {};
for(var key in obj) {
  var prefix = key.slice(0,2);
  if (max[prefix] === undefined || +max[prefix].split('=')[1] < obj[key]){
    max[prefix] = key + '=' + obj[key];
  }
}

// Concatenate the max values into a string
var maxString = '';
for(key in max){
  maxString += max[key] + ', ';
}
maxString = maxString.trim();
```

Comment: Please try my changes.

Comment: It only prints the last value from same group even the first value is the biggest....

Comment: If you're testing it on the exact `obj` from the original question, the keys are all the same, so they will get overwritten. Can you edit your example `obj` to contain properties that break this solution? I just tried with several different key-values and can't find the bug you're describing.

Comment: you are right! now it works. I apologize and thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: You're very welcome! If you're satisfied with this solution, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79243/discussion-between-user2734550-and-danny-delott).

Comment: Okay, take a look at my edit that satisfied the new constraints.

Comment: Ok, I understand why you put '+' before returned array now, it converts to number if value of array is a numbered string or a number. Wonder if it is faster than parseInt/Math.floor.

Answer (score 4):

You can generate the `max` object dynamically, without hardcoding the group names:

```js
obj = {
 'ab-1': 9,
 'ab-2': 3,  
 'cd-1': 1,
 'cd-2': 5,
 'ef-1': 3,
 'ef-2': 4,
};

max = [], group = null;

Object.keys(obj).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  var g = key.substr(0, 2);
  if(g == group)
    max.push(Math.max(max.pop(), obj[key]));
  else {
    group = g;
    max.push(obj[key]);
  }
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(max))
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, but if I need to get the value 9,5,4, I have to use for in loop again to get them. Just curious if there is a way to get result by to looping only once?

Answer (score 2):

This will create a new object with the maximum values of the first object:

```js
var obj = {
  'ab-xxx': 2,
  'ab-yyy': 3,  
  'cd-xxx': 1,
  'cd-yyy': 5,
  'ef-xxx': 3,
  'ef-yyy': 4
},
newobj= {};

for(var i in obj) {
  var key= i.split('-')[0];
  
  newobj[key]= Math.max(newobj[key] || -Infinity, obj[i]);
}

document.body.innerHTML= JSON.stringify(newobj);
```

---

> Would you explain the part Math.max()?

This line:

```
newobj[key]= Math.max(newobj[key] || -Infinity, obj[i]);
```

… is shorthand for this:

```
if(!newobj[key]) newobj[key]= -Infinity;
newobj[key]= Math.max(newobj[key], obj[i]);
```

This is called "null coalescing":  If the operand on the left-hand side of the OR operator (`||`) is *falsy* (in this case `undefined`), then return the operand on the right (in this case `-Infinity`).

If one of the arguments of `Math.max()` is `undefined`, then `NaN` is returned, so this prevents that from happening.

---

> get the max number instead of a new obj with new property name

I like @georg 's answer a lot, because it loops only once.  But here's how to do it with my code:

```js
var obj = {
  'ab-xxx': 2,
  'ab-yyy': 3,  
  'cd-xxx': 1,
  'cd-yyy': 5,
  'ef-xxx': 3,
  'ef-yyy': 4
},
newobj= {};

for(var i in obj) {
  var key= i.split('-')[0];
  
  newobj[key]= Math.max(newobj[key] || -Infinity, obj[i]);
}

var s= [];
Object.keys(newobj).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  s.push(newobj[key]);
});

document.body.innerHTML= s.join(',');
```

In JavaScript, object keys may be in any order, regardless of how they're defined.

If not for that, this:

```
Object.keys(newobj).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  s.push(newobj[key]);
});
```

… could be greatly simplified:

```
for(var key in newobj) {
  s.push(newobj[key]);
});
```

---

> a solution to print original property name with its value like this string ab--hello=3, cd-you=2.

`Math.max()` won't help in this case.  You'll need to do a comparison, and you'll need to keep track of both the key and its value.  Here's a solution:

```js
var obj = {
  'ab-xxx': 2,
  'ab-hello': 3,  
  'cd-you': 2,
  'cd-zzz': 1,
  'ef-xxx': 3,
  'ef-yyy': 4
},
newobj= {};

for(var i in obj) {
  var txt= i.split('-')[0];
  
  if(!newobj[txt] || (obj[i] > newobj[txt].val)) {
    newobj[txt]= {
      txt: i,
      val: obj[i]
    }
  }
}

var s= [];
Object.keys(newobj).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  s.push(newobj[key].txt+'='+newobj[key].val);
});

document.body.innerHTML= s.join(', ');
```

Comment: `||` is dangerous here, consider `ab-xxx: -1, ab-yyy: -2`.

Comment: Would you explain the part Math.max()? I know how to use Math.max but not the way you use it. Also it would be nice if I can just get the max number instead of a new obj with new property name

Comment: @Rick Hitchcock Awesome! I understand the Math part now. I know you have answered my question, I really appreciate your answer. but it would be perfect if you can also provide a solution to print original property name with its value like this string ab--hello=3, cd-you=2. I really want to know the possible solution for this too.I have been trying to do so but no luck.